# Eslint no-console

Tags: javascript, nodejs, npm

¿Cómo lograr que no me aparezca el error al querer depurar con `console.log()` usando Eslint?

La pregunta también es valida para los `alert()`

Mensaje de error:

> error: Unexpected console statement (no-console) at
>   src\components\ejemplo.vue:1:7:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar este comentario en la linea que pones el console:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-console <-- esto desactiva el lint en la siguiente linea
console.error = function (message) {
  throw new Error(message);
};
```

o lo puedes poner asi:

```
console.error = function (message) {  // eslint-disable-line no-console <-- desactiva el lint en esta linea
  throw new Error(message);
};
```

Alguna de las opciones de arriba es la mejor practica pues evita que tengas console.log o cualquier otro en un lugar no deseado, sin embargo, si aún asi prefieres deshabilitar la opción en tus reglas debes agregar esto:

```
rules: {
    'no-console': 'off',
},
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono perfectamente.

Comment: Igual tengo una duda, las "rules" lo he visto en diferentes foros, sin embargo, no he encontrado su ruto. Estoy utilizando node.js con Vue.js